# Finding the definite integral of a trigonometric expression

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Find the integral of $$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{{\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}} \cdot \sin(\theta)d\theta}$$
I got $$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}{\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)} \cdot (\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))d\theta}$$
But, I'm stuck here.

Comment: Do you know of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)?

Comment: I don't know beta function. Is there any other way without using the beta function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested in knowing how to do this **without** using the Beta function, try the following steps. But I'm not going to write it out in full because it would take too long.

Call the integral $I$. First do integration by parts, and we find that $$I=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos 2\theta\cos \theta}{\sqrt{\sin 2\theta}}d\theta$$

Now add this form of $I$ to the original form and get $$2I=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos \theta}{\sqrt{\sin 2\theta}}d\theta$$

hence$$4I=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{\sin 2\theta}}{\sin\theta}d\theta$$

Now substitute $t=\sqrt{\tan \theta}$ and you end up with a well known integral, featured many times on MSE, requiring a rather tedious partial fraction decomposition, but you get there in the end...

I hope this is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

The integral
$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(2\theta)} \, \sin\theta \, d\theta$$
is evaluated by making use of the Beta function. This is seen as follows.
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(2\theta)} \, \sin\theta \, d\theta \\
&= \sqrt{2} \, \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{3/2}(\theta) \, \cos^{1/2}(\theta) \, d\theta \\
&= \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \, B\left(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\right) \\
&= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \, \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{4 \, \sqrt{2}} = \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: That's very nice indeed! If someone is interested in longer calculations, a primitive is given by $$\frac{1}{4} \left(\arcsin(\sin(t)-\cos (t))-2 \sqrt{\sin (2 t)} \cos (t)+\log \left(\sin (t)+\sqrt{\sin (2 t)}+\cos
   (t)\right)\right).$$

Comment: Now that was efficient!  +1

Answer (score 4):

A *slightly* different approach: With the change of variables $u=\cos\theta$, you arrive at
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin2\theta}\sin\theta\,d\theta=\sqrt2\int_0^1 u^{1/2}(1-u^2)^{1/4}\,du$$
Another substitution, $\sqrt t=u$, yields
$$\begin{align*}\sqrt2\int_0^1 t^{1/4}(1-t)^{1/4}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^{-1/2}\right)\,dt&=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\int_0^1 t^{3/4-1}(1-t)^{5/4-1}\,dt\\[1ex]&=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4}\right)\end{align*}$$
which is equivalent to Leucippus' solution.